# If I simultaneously change and omit part of a quote, should I include ellipsis next to the brackets?

Tags: quotations, ellipses, citation, square-brackets

I feel it would be easiest to explain using my specific situation as an example. I am writing an essay in which I plan to include the following quotation from a secondary source:

> The more she talks, the more vivid my fantasy of **us listening to sober podcasts in her minivan while driving to the petting zoo** becomes.

I would like to replace the bolded text with simply "our friendship" for the sake of succinctness (which I feel is okay as it does not change the meaning of the quote). I already know to put it in square brackets. However, since I am omitting quite a bit of the quote as well, should I also include ellipsis? Like so:

> The more she talks, the more vivid my fantasy of ... [our friendship] becomes.

Comment: I don't think the ellipsis is necessary. It's generally understood that the replacement can be significantly shorter from the original when you use brackets. That's often the reason for the replacement in the first place.

Comment: Also, anything outside the brackets is assumed to be literally copied from the original. So if you do use ellipsis, they should be *inside* the brackets: [... our friendship]